# How create a new variable according field value

Tags: 7, theming

Please I need a hand, I would like to create a new variable like the native "frontpage" variable. I have a content type called "Config", in this CT I have some boolean fields and I need check for this field values to print a view in my page.tpl

Something like this, my example field "display reviews block?", its may be set "yes" or "no". So, I need create a new variable "$display_reviews" according this value and print this in page.tpl:

```
<?php if (isset($display_reviews)): ?>
 <?php print views_embed_view('reviews', 'block'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Sincerly, I dont know how to do this, but i tried something like this:

```
function mytemplate_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node'])) {
    $n = $variables['node'];

    if ($variables['node']->type == 'config') {

        if (isset($n->field_display_reviews == 'yes') {
          $variables['display_reviews'] = 'this variable need be created';

        }
    }    

 }
}
```

UPDATE

Considering I want to print this variable in my node.tpl not in my page.tpl, I have decided to try with directly query, I dont know if is the better and fast way, but this is my code. Its not working yet, this is broking my site, but now I can display the FIELD ID. Im trying to use the field_attach_load to get the field value but no luck:

```
/**
* Implementation of preprocess_().
*/
function mytemplate_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {

$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'config')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  // value 1 from boolean field
  ->fieldCondition('field_display_reviews','value', '1', '=');
$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $stories = $result['node'];

  $fields = field_info_instances('node', 'config');

  // Get id of field
  $reviews = $fields['field_display_reviews']['field_id'];
  field_attach_load('node', $stories, FIELD_LOAD_CURRENT, array('field_id' => $reviews));
  $output = field_get_items('node', $stories, 'field_display_reviews');

  $variables['display_reviews'] = $output;



}

}
```

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. Just to make sure, is your theme's name `mytemplate`? If not are you replacing it with the actual theme name?

Comment: Hi, no no `mytemplate` is not my theme name, but Im aware of this. I put mytemplate as just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already there, i think you didn't extract the value of the `field_display_reviews` correctly, try the following:

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mytemplate_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node'])) {
    $node = $variables['node'];
    if ($node->type == 'config') {
      if (
        isset($node->field_display_reviews[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])
        && $node->field_display_reviews[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == 'yes'
      ) {
        $variables['display_reviews'] = 'this variable need be created';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: if your `display_reviews` field of type `Boolean` the value it will be `1` instead of `yes`, print the value of `$node->field_display_reviews[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']` before if to see.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. I found my error, in the true, I want print the `display_reviews` variable in my node.tpl not in page.tpl. So `preprocess_page` is not for this case. I tried do to the same with `preprocess_node` but its returns the "Notice: Undefined variable: display_reviews" error. Now I got confused becasuse my homepage node is type 'basic', is there where i will print the variable, but the field that i need rescue is from node type 'config'. Can you guide me how can I create this variable?

Comment: Im almost there! Iam using the `preprocess_node` and `field_get_items`, but i have not yet able to rescue the field value. what i did until now:

`function mytemplate_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {
 $node = $variables['node'];
 $field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_display_reviews');
 // Get the value from the first item
 $reviews = $field_items[0]['value'];
   $variables['display_reviews'] = $reviews;
}`

Comment: Try with `function mytemplate_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $variables['display_reviews'] = $node->field_display_reviews[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
} `

Comment: For this way, its not working. I have decided to try with direct query.

Comment: Why you need a direct query to get `field_display_reviews` ??